# Simple page container

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to have a simple ContentPage or something similar that hosts another page without any of the frills that come with tab page or navigation page? I want this host page to be essentially invisible.

The idea is to pop up a login modal on the root page and then, when the user has logged in, switch the contents in the background so that when the login page is popped off, it reveals new content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the NavigationStack available so you can push & pop pages, you need to use NavigationPage.  You have a couple of reasonable options though:

1. Reassign Application.Current.MainPage whenever you want a page transition. This won't create a page stack, but will show the new content when reassigned without animation.  So rather than thinking about a login modal then popping it off, just set the current page to the login page, then on login, set the current page to the content you want the user to see.
2. Use a NavigationPage as the Application.Current.MainPage, but then call SetHasNavigationBar(page, false) to avoid the extra elements that come with NavigationPage.  You may need to call NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false); for every page you push on the stack to avoid the back button.

Comment: Will give it a go.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like having a navigation page inside of a navigation page. e.g. it doesn't remove the space for the top page's navigation bar and it puts the tool bar buttons from the content page in both navigation bars.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that pushing navigation page onto a navigation page doesn't work well.  If you needed to, you could hide the "outer" navigation page's navigation bar by using SetHasNavigationBar on it, but I'd try to avoid nesting like that.  I don't think I implied doing that in my answer...